# ArXiv Submission Error : Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: arxiv

I'm uploading my PDFLatex submission on ArXiv and I'm getting an error during the stamping of the paper with the arXiv watermark.

Last few lines of stacktrace:

```
Output written on submission1.pdf (3 pages, 617693 bytes).
Transcript written on submission1.log.

[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'submission1.aux' (1473441304 >= 1473441303)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'submission1.out' (1473441304 >= 1473441303)
[verbose]: now stamping pdf file 'submission1.pdf' with stamp 'arXiv:submit/1661293 [cs.AI] 9 Sep 2016'
[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: an error occurred during stamp operation, reverted to original file


[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Has anyone faced such an issue? The tex file is compiling the PDF perfectly on my machine. Is this an issue with ArXiv's servers or is it something on my end?

Comment: This is a problem on arXiv's side and not something that occurs related to your code. The issue as you can see in the end of the log is that the arXiv-id stamp fails, and then fails to revert to the original "unstamped" pdf. The fix of adding a `00README.XXX` will address this issue, but it's an arXiv problem not a latex issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating the solution that worked for me here. I had contacted Arxiv Help via email about this problem. Their solution was to disable the stamp generation by adding "nostamp" to the 00README.XXX file along with the submission.

https://arxiv.org/help/00README#nostamp

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem when including the **axessibility** package to my submission.
Apparently arxiv and this package don't go very well together. So just removing the line `\usepackage[accsupp]{axessibility}` from my arxiv submission fixed the issue. (credits to arxiv support)